# Branch coverage never reaches 100%

Tags: .net, unit-testing

The test report never reaches 100% of branch coverage because of the statement below.

Why there are 6 branches to cover on a simple `if` condition with only one comparison?

This occurs on `if`s that compare nullable `DateTime`s.

[Github repo](https://github.com/ZackStone/branch-coverage-problem)

[image: Test coverage report 1]

EDIT:

A friend of mine gave me the suggestion bellow.
Now it has 100% branch coverage, but we still don't now **WHY** the first solution doesn't cover it at all.

[image: Test coverage report 2]

Comment: Which test framework? Which version of dotnet? What coverage tool? Do you have a test project you can share (on GitHub for example) that shows this problem? What's the datatype of `DataFim`? Is DataFim a nullable value?

Comment: @jessehouwing xunit, using this VS extension: https://github.com/the-dext/RunCoverletReport/blob/master/README.md, I going to upload a example code in github soon, `DataFim` is a nullable DateTime.

Comment: Make sure you include values of `DataFim == null` in your tests.

Comment: If it is nullable then you need to add null test, non null min value and non null not minvalue test.

Comment: - there are already this 3 unit tests: 1. null, 2. non-null not minvalue, 3. min-value
- I tried to change the if statement to `if (MyDate != null && MyDate == DateTime.MinValue)`, but running the coverage report again, it covers 6 of 8 branches.

Comment: If both the DateTime values there are nullable, the equivalent lowered expression is `if (a.HasValue && b.HasValue && (!a.HasValue || a.GetValueOrDefault() == b.GetValueOrDefault())`, maybe this can shed some light on which branch wasn't taken?